# How to use 'facet' to create multiple density plot in GGPLOT

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following data created on the fly:

```
 > df <- data.frame( cbind(rnorm(200),rnorm(200, mean=.8),rnorm(200, mean=.9),rnorm(200, mean=1),rnorm(200, mean=.2),rnorm(200, mean=.3)),rnorm(200, mean=4),rnorm(200, mean=.5))
 > colnames(df) <- c("w.cancer","w.normal","x.cancer","x.normal","y.cancer","y.normal","z.cancer","z.normal")
 > df_log<-log2(df) # ignore the warning with NA
 > head(df_log)
```

What I want to do is to create multiple plots in one panel like the sketch below using 'facet'.
How can I go about it?

[image]

Comment: Yes. Fig above is just a sketch and it won't reflect the real data for sure.

Comment: +1 Beautiful sketches.

Comment: @neversaint did you create these sketches by hand, or using some kind of software tool?

Comment: Use your sketches (instead of ggplot!). They are really really beautiful!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'll have to prepare your data first. I've illustrated this on your `data.frame df` as it is a proper normal distribution.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)

df.m <- melt(df, "id")
df.m$grp1 <- factor(gsub("\\..*$", "", df.m$variable))
df.m$grp2 <- factor(gsub(".*\\.", "", df.m$variable))

p <- ggplot(data = df.m, aes(x=value)) + geom_density(aes(fill=grp2), alpha = 0.4)
p <- p + facet_wrap( ~ grp1)
p + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image: ggplot2_facet_example]

Doing the same by replacing `df` with `df_log` you'd get something like this:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
df_log$id <- 1:nrow(df_log)

df.m <- melt(df_log, "id")
df.m$grp1 <- factor(gsub("\\..*$", "", df.m$variable))
df.m$grp2 <- factor(gsub(".*\\.", "", df.m$variable))

p <- ggplot(data = df.m, aes(x=value)) + geom_density(aes(fill=grp2), alpha = 0.5)
p <- p + facet_wrap( ~ grp1)
p
```

[image: ggplog2_facet_log]