# How to create a distribution plot faceted that contain title in x an y axis GGPLOT

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have data that looks like this

```
    df <- data.frame(c("Cell1","Cell2","NK-Cell"),c("K","L","S","L","K","S","S","L","K"),abs(log2(abs(rnorm(180)))))    
colnames(df) <- c("ctype","tissue","exp")
```

I'm trying to create a plot that looks like this. 
[image]

Comment: Your example data only contains data for the diagonal of that example plot....

Comment: Oops. I updated the code.

Comment: -1. I'd like to think that after [a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623348/how-to-use-facet-to-create-multiple-density-plot-in-ggplot) on facetting and density plots and [many other simlar facet-related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A67405+%5Bggplot%5D+facet) from you, you should at least show the code you've tried... let alone be able to learn something out of the questions you ask.

Comment: See the Facets section: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

General idea in this situation would be to use faceting to get this kind of plot.

```
ggplot(df,aes(exp))+geom_density()+facet_grid(tissue~ctype)
```

There are two empty plots because there are no `Cell2` values for the `tissue S` and no `NK-Cell` values for `tissue L`.

[image]